# where to find outputdir or dist-files when use "vue-cli-service serve"

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I run "vue-cli-service build" using npm or other, I can get a "dist" ouput dir which defined in vue.config.js.

```
    module.exports = {
      publicPath: '/',
      outputDir: 'dist',
    }
```

But, how can I find or where to find or how to defined the "dist" dir if I run "vue-cli-service serve"? I can't see any output dir in the project.

Needs help! Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In development mode (the `serve` keyword) files are kept in RAM only - they are not persisted on the hard drive. If you are running the project at the default URL of `http://localhost:8080` - then you should be able to see a listing of all the assets by going to `http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server`

There is a config option to ask the Webpack-dev-server to write files to disk -

webpack4: https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverwritetodisk-

webpack5(should be): https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverdevmiddleware

Comment: Thanks,I was very confused about this.is there an official document mentioned it?

Comment: I was wondering why my asp.net VS project kept serving me old files! The project was a template that had Vue-cli-service server running on build, and I was so confused why even though the files in the "dist" folder were fresh, the vue-cli-service server gave the old... Restarted vue-cli-service serve.

Comment: This ans help me to solve my issue. I was using development build  and  nginx mapping  was not able to find the index. page. After  changing my build to production it work fine.